# PHP Register autoload function from constructor in the same class

Tags: php, autoload

Not sure why this doesn't work.. trying a number of different syntax to call register the "autoLoad" function with spl_autoload_register, and I keep getting an error, function not found.

```
class ClassLoader {

//Directories
private $dir_path        = '';
private $directories     = ['config/',
                            'core/',
                            'helpers/',
                            'modules/',
                            'classes/'];

//Add your file naming formats here
private $fileNameFormats = ['%s.php',
                            '%s.class.php',
                            'class.%s.php',
                            '%s.inc.php'];

public function __construct($paths) {
    $this->dir_path = $paths['root']. '/';
    $loader = $this->{autoLoader()};
    spl_autoload_register($loader);
}

function autoLoader($className) {

    foreach($this->directories as $directory) {
        foreach($this->fileNameFormats as $fileNameFormat) {
            $path = $this->dir_path . $directory.sprintf($fileNameFormat, $className);
            try {
                if (!include($path)) {
                    throw new Exception ('<b>Error - Missing class:</b>' . $path);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                echo
                    '<p><b>EXCEPTION</b><br />Message: '
                    . $e->getMessage()
                    . '<br />File: '
                    . $e->getFile()
                    . '<br />Line: '
                    . $e->getLine()
                    . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As per [the docs on callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), to reference a class function as a callback, you need an array, where the first element is the class name or an object that represents an instance of the class, along with a string of the function you want to call from that class.

So, you should be using:

```
spl_autoload_register( array( $this, 'autoLoader'));
```

Comment: oh, my bad, didn't realize i had to access it that way... thanks!